# Where can buy syrup in the US

Tags: usa, food-and-drink

I'm looking to buy syrup suitable to prepare drinks. In other words I look for the concentrate to buy so I can dilute it at home.

Something like found on [this page](https://produkte.migros.ch/sortiment/supermarkt/lebensmittel/getraenke-heiss-kalt/sirup-soda) (Sorry only available in German/French/Italian but not English).

In case it matters I'm living in California, more specifically in the San Francisco Bay Area.

Comment: There are "German" stores in Mountain View and probably in other areas of the Bay area, but have you tried your neighborhood Safeway or Trader Joe's?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I'll try that out. I tried Safeway, Trader Joe's and Wallmart so far.

Comment: I think the UK equivalent of this would be `squash`. Try googling "orange squash" to see if that fits your criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soda syrup isn't something typically sold in grocery stores in the US, (though it can be found in a few places) but it is available on the market generally.

I was able to find quite a selection of syrups by [searching Amazon.com's soft drink category for "syrup"](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=node%3D16318231&field-keywords=syrup). These range in size from 500mL bottles you may be accustomed to, to 5 *gallon* (~ 19 L) boxes intended for use in commercial soda fountains.

There are also companies which specialize in it, such as [Northwoods Soda](http://www.northwoodssoda.com/), [Prairie Moon](http://www.prairiemoon.biz/) and [Pittsburgh Soda Pop](http://pittsburghsodapop.com/).